# How to match string with hypens in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match certain parts of a URL that has the following form:

```
http://example.com/somepath/this-is-composed-of-hypens-3144/someotherpath
```

More precisely, I want to match only the part that is composed of all hypens and ends in numbers. So, I want to extract the part `this-is-composed-of-hypens-3144` in the above URL. I have something like this:

```
const re = /[a-z]*-[a-z]*-[0-9]*/gis;
const match = re.exec(url);
return (match && match.length) ? match[0] : null;
```

However, this works only if there are 2 hypens, however, the number of hypens in my case can be arbitrary. How can I make my regex work for arbitrary number of hypens?

Comment: Are there digits **only** within the last part?

Comment: Isn't it better to just excract the second segment of the URL? first is `/somepath` second is `/this-is-composed-of-hypens-3144`

Comment: `/\/([a-z]+(?:-[a-z]*)*-[0-9]+)(?=\/|$)/i;`? See https://regex101.com/r/bJEuLk/1

Comment: @VLAZ It's not always in the second segment

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks works. If you submit as an answer, I can accept.

Comment: @Toto yes, they are

Comment: Well, then @WiktorStribiżew answer is working.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, I just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/\/([a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*-[0-9]+)(?:\/|$)/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bJEuLk/4)

**Details**

- `\/` - a `/` char
- `([a-z]+(?:-[a-z]*)*-[0-9]+)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[a-z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
  - `(?:-[a-z]+)*` - 0+ occurrences of `-` followed with 1+ ASCII letters
- `(?:\/|$)` - either `/` or end of string.

If there can be any word chars, not just ASCII letters, you may replace each `[a-z]` with `\w`.

```js
var s = "http://example.com/somepath/this-is-composed-of-hypens-3144/someotherpath";
var m = s.match(/\/([a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*-[0-9]+)(?:\/|$)/i);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```